# My Internet connection keeps failing

Tags: 12.10, internet

Hello. I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit. While I am just browsing the Internet, network connectivity is fine. However, when I watch a movie or download something the Internet connection fails. If I reboot the modem, everything works, but not for long. How do I correct this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then **edit** your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bug reports describing such symptoms. Most likely a driver bug. Please search https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux for the names of your network hardware drivers.